is there a way to the ros1 combined_robot_hw in ros2?
Does ros2 have combined_robot_hw? I have two robot arms; how do I set them up so that the read/write for the two arms happens at the same time?
I have seen https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/example_15/doc/userdoc.rst
. This example spawns two robots. But not sure that these two robots are combined.

I suppose that this example is what you are looking for. (I'd be happy if you leave a review there if it helped).
If you load two hardware components in the same controller_manager, the read/write will happen in the same update loop.

Hi, thank you for your reply, the actually fix for our side is to set:
ArmHardware::on_init(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo& info) {   info_ = info; ... }
at the beginning of the on_init  function.
Otherwise, the spawned hardware will be confused with the name.
